# about python list step issue when the element is long type

Tags: python, list

In [2]: list=range(627)

In [3]: list[::150]

Out[3]: [0, 150, 300, 450, 600]

the above code is right,but if i use the bellow code,caution:the l means long type,
the return result is not like above,what's the hell?

In [4]: list=[1323l,123123l,4444l,12312312l]

In [5]: list=[1323l,123123l,4444l,12312312l]

In [6]: list[::2]

Out[6]: [1323L, 4444L]

Comment: I'm really not understanding the problem. You're making the values in your second example be long types by putting an l(lowercase L) after each number. It's slicing exactly as it should be. Can you clarify what is wrong?

Comment: sorry,i made a mistake,i think the step return is the indices,and i use a range(0,627,150) as a test example,and the value & index is the same,so i thought it return index not value,finally i use range(0,len(list),step) get what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step denotes the multiples of *indices* that are included in the slice, not of the actual values contained in the array. In your second example:

```
list[0] = 1323L
list[1] = 123123L
list[2] = 4444L
list[3] = 12312312L
```

Since you're using the default argument for the start of the slice, it will start at the first element (`list[0]`), and it will get every 2nd element after that, so it will also get `list[2]`. It does not look at what those elements are, only at their indices.